# How do I get text above and below text?

Tags: text-manipulation

How would I do `{text}_{i=1}^{i=n}` with the written *exactly* above and below the text?

Hope you can help!

Comment: Without a proper context and some information about the intended meaning and use it's hard to say which is the best option. In the preamble: `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the document `\[
\overset{i=n}{\underset{i=1}{text}}
\]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
\stackunder{\stackon{\text{text}}{\scriptstyle i=n}}{\scriptstyle i=1}
\quad
\underset{i=1}{\overset{i=n}{\text{text}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The gap between the text and the over/under-set is defined with `\setstackgap{S}{2pt}` for the `stackengine` approach on the left.

Either of these approaches will work in `\displaystyle` (shown) or in `\textstyle`.  Note, however, that in `\textstyle`, the line spacing will be affected.

Answer (score 11):

I assume you'll want the subscript and superscript material to be in display-style math mode and to use a smaller font size than what's used for the "text" string. Sort of like `\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}`, except for the use of the string "text" instead of the large summation symbol, right?

If these assumptions are correct, you could use the `\DeclareMathOperator*` directive of the `amsmath` package to achieve your objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sometext}{text} % "\text" is already taken...
\begin{document}
\[
\sometext_{i=1}^{i=n} % not "{\sometext}"
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\[ \overset{i=n}{\underset{i=1}{text}} \]` could also be an option. No info about the context for the expression, it's difficult to decide the best approach. +1, by the way.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - It definitely would be helpful to have more context. Your suggestion has the advantage of "working" in both inline-style and display-style math modes.

Comment: Does this not limit the text to the letters t-e-x-t, rather than arbitrary text?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I honestly don't know what the intended use case may be. I was assuming that the string "text" (or whatever it may be in practice...) is meant to be fixed. Naturally, this assumption may not be correct.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other suggestions you could use: `\mathop` together with `\operatorname` from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mymathop[1]{\mathop{\operatorname{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\[
  \mymathop{text}_{i=1}^{i=n}
\]

This is in a paragraph: $\mymathop{text}_{i=1}^{i=n}$ or $\displaystyle\mymathop{text}_{i=1}^{i=n}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\begin{document}
Some $\stackrel[i=1]{i=n}{\mathrm{text}}$ in line.
\end{document}
```