# Place one math expression over the other

Tags: amsmath

The following formula appears in the [Stanford ML Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/N09c6/cost-function-intuition-i):

[image: 'Above' example]

How do I express this format, in which `minimize` is in line with the `J(...)` expression, and directly above the Thetas?

I tried looking for a similar example in the [LaTeX/Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) book, but did not notice anything similar.

Comment: related: [How do I get text above and below text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256374/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The `*` form here gives the "limits" setting with the subscript below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*\minz{minimize}
\begin{document}

\[\minz_{\theta_0,\theta_1}J(\theta_0\theta_1)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works like a charm, but being a newbie, I fail to understand the code. Would you please be able to further explain how and why it works, or even paste a link so I can further read?

Comment: @AdamMatan basically what you ask for is standard behaviour for "math operators` eg `\sum` where the subscript is placed under the operator in display mode. `amsdoc amsmath` will give you the documentation of the amsmath package command I used.